# Jenkins change job's svn path programatically

Tags: jenkins, svn

I am searching for a best practice for switching svn repo paths from many jenkins jobs at once.

We have many different jobs which all define an svn path and poll our svn repo every 5 minutes.
Normally we build all projects from their trunks (subversion plugin  2.7.1).
But sometimes for bugfix reasons we want to be able to build all or certain projects from predefined tags or branches.

This switch should be made on a global job level not in the actual jobs themselves.

I have defined a job which lists all svn paths for our projects (using List Subversion tags plugin).
When the job gets fired every selected path gets written into a properties file with a key-value pair like "SVN_Projectname=tags/TAGNAME".
When no subversion tag is selected for a project the default vaule "SVN_Projectname=trunk" is written to the file for that project.
This is running without any issues...

I created a test job with a textparameter called "SVN_Projectname" and used the envInject plugin option "Prepare an environment for the run" with "Override Build Parameters" to read the already existent properties file.
Also the subversion plugin is provided with the parameter "${SVN_Projectname}" for the read parameter value from file.
Additional credentials (realm and credentials) are also provided and polling is activated for that job too.

Running that job manually is no problem, but the actual value from the file is generating polling results of the following error (scm-polling.log):

```
Started on 11.10.2017 14:53:00
Received SCM poll call on master for XXX_TAG on 11.10.2017 14:53:00
ERROR: Failed to check repository revision for http://XXX/svn/repository_XXX/Project/tags/tagname
[8mha:AAAAWB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQSmjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc8DzHWhSE4tKMnjz/PLL0ldFVf2c+b/lb8MDAwVRQxSaBqxXTRIIQMEMIIUFgAAckCEiWAAAAA=[0morg.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: E200015: ISVNAuthentication provider did not provide credentials; HTTP authorization cancelled.
svn: E200015: ISVNAuthentication provider did not provide credentials; HTTP authorization cancelled.
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:66)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:798)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:391)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:379)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:862)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:698)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:118)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1049)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:189)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.getRevisionNumber(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:119)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:195)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:46)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteGetInfo.run(SvnRemoteGetInfo.java:46)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteGetInfo.run(SvnRemoteGetInfo.java:31)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.doInfo(SVNWCClient.java:2535)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.parseSvnInfo(SubversionSCM.java:1228)
    at hudson.scm.CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.call(CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.java:79)
    at hudson.scm.CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.call(CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.java:27)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(SubversionSCM.java:1425)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(SCM.java:391)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.poll(SCM.java:408)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject._poll(AbstractProject.java:1460)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.poll(AbstractProject.java:1363)
    at jenkins.triggers.SCMTriggerItem$SCMTriggerItems$Bridge.poll(SCMTriggerItem.java:128)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.runPolling(SCMTrigger.java:557)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.run(SCMTrigger.java:603)
    at hudson.util.SequentialExecutionQueue$QueueEntry.run(SequentialExecutionQueue.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: ISVNAuthentication provider did not provide credentials; HTTP authorization cancelled.
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:728)
    ... 34 more
Done. Took 0,17 sec
No changes
```

While i have provided all credentials to the job and starting the job manually, there is no problem. I dont understand what the actual problem is...

Or is there a better way of automating such a behavior?

Maybe manipulating the projects config.xmls with a changed svn path is a possibility?
But then jenkins service would have to be restarted? and i would prefer to make the change on the fly ^^